# Not able to build an APK in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/Users/prashantsingh/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/file_picker-5.3.3/android/build.gradle' line: 24
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':file_picker'.

> No signature of method: build_f3q32pyguxvldsk3l3pwcva1z.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_f3q32pyguxvldsk3l3pwcva1z$_run_closure2) values: [build_f3q32pyguxvldsk3l3pwcva1z$_run_closure2@2c3d05f8]

on runing, flutter build apk --flavor staging
it is throwing above error

I have tried:
flutter clean
flutter pub cache clean

but none of them work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

check your 24 no. line in android/gradle file or upgrade or downgrade the file_picker package